# Add function to event runtime

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TFormOrderAdd.DBEdit1DblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FormSelectEmp: TForm;
  SelectEmpDBGrid: TDBGrid;

begin
  FormSelectEmp := TForm.Create(Self);
  SelectEmpDBGrid :=  TDBGrid.Create(Self);
  SelectEmpDBGrid.Parent := FormSelectEmp;
  SelectEmpDBGrid.Align := alClient;
  SelectEmpDBGrid.DataSource := DMl.DataSourceViewEmpList;
  FormSelectEmp.ShowModal;
  SelectEmpDBGrid.OnDblClick := AddSelectedEmp;
  FormSelectEmp.Close;
end;

procedure TFormOrderAdd.AddSelectedEmp;
begin
  DBEdit1.Text := Dml.ADOQueryViewEmpList.FieldByName('ID').Text;
end;
```

How i can add my procedure to OnDblClick Event?
I tryed just assign, but compiller says: [dcc32 Error] OrderAdd.pas(66): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Comment: The same way you assign any other property, just pass the handler's name. Also, shouldn't that be before `ShowModal`? What does your procedure look like? You can't pass just any.

Comment: [dcc32 Error] OrderAdd.pas(66): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

Comment: SelectEmpDBGrid.OnDblClick := AddSelectedEmp(Self);

Comment: I mean, what does `AddSelectedEmp` look like? Actually, it looks like you're attempting to `call` it rather than `assign` it. Remove `(Self)` from it. Please [Edit] your question with these full details.

Comment: [dcc32 Error] OrderAdd.pas(66): E2009 Incompatible types: 'Parameter lists differ', Need same number of parameters like "OnDblClick"

Comment: It looks like you have not provided an appropriate event handler procedure. It must have a proper signature. `AddSelectedEmp` should have `(Sender: TObject)` on it.  Please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956399/988445

Comment: I'm edited question, i just need insert text from selected field to dbedit

Comment: @димасоколов: That may be, but you still have to assign a procedure with the proper signature. Your `TFormOrder.AddSelectedEmp` should be `procedure TFormOrder.AddSelectedEmp(Sender: TObject);`.

Comment: @Rudy, haven't I just tried to say that in the answer below? If there is something wrong with formulating, let me know or edit the answer, please (that's what I was about to say).

Comment: @Victoria: Sure, but I merely reacted to his comment with another comment. Your example is nice, but I tried to spell it out using his code (using his procedure name), not yours. I have the impression he didn't quite get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must create a matching event method prototype in a class that you then assign to the event handler (for the [**TDBGrid**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.DBGrids.TDBGrid) control's [**OnDblClick**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.OnDblClick) event it is the [**TNotifyEvent**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TNotifyEvent)), so you can write for example:

```
type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DBEdit1: TDBEdit;
    DBGrid1: TDBGrid;
  private
    procedure Form1Create(Sender: TObject);
    procedure MyGridDblClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

implementation

procedure TForm1.Form1Create(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { it doesn't matter if you create the component at runtime,
    this is a common principle of assigning event methods at
    runtime - they just have to match the method prototypes }
  DBGrid1.OnDblClick := MyGridDblClick;
end;

procedure TForm1.MyGridDblClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { to access the grid instance in case more than one grid
    uses this handler you can use TDBGrid(Sender) or safer
    cast (Sender as TDBGrid) }
  DBEdit1.Text := TDBGrid(Sender).DataSource.Dataset.FieldByName('ID').Text;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. And now i have new problem: if i use ShowModal instead Show application stuck in vcl forms module :Application.HandleMessage;
          if Application.Terminated then ModalResult := mrCancel else
            if ModalResult <> 0 then CloseModal; and event not fired

Comment: As was mentioned in comment to your question, you must assign the event handler before you call `ShowModal`. And read the another answer here to address another problem that you meet (it's correct but a bit out of scope of what you asked).

Comment: How i can close form after AddSelectedEmp was executed? From AddSelectedEmp i cant access to form.

Comment: It's out of scope of this question, but well, if the assigned method is a part of the same form class (as shown in the example), you can simply use `Close;` method after you finish your work in that event handler (or set `ModalResult` property to whatever modal result you need to return). If you are assigning a handler method from another class, you can use commonly this to reach the form on which the grid is placed `(GetParentForm(TControl(Sener))).Close;` or set `ModalResult` respectively after you do your work in the event method.

Comment: not work, but i find Screen.ActiveForm.Close; it work

Comment: @димасоколов: What do you mean you can't access the form from your handler? If it is a method of the form, as in Victoria's answer, you should be able to access it. So did you do what Victoria wrote, or just something a bit like it?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used Screen.ActiveForm.Close; I can't access because "AddSelectedEmp" procedure is on Main Form, but hundler is on FormSelectEmp, its form 
Inherited from TForm (FormSelectEmp: TForm;), but not MainForm, because i dont want all visible components from Main form on new runtime created form. AddSelectedEmp procedure nothing know about new created  form.

Comment: procedure TFormOrderAdd.DBEditEmpDblClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  FormSelectEmp: TForm;
  SelectEmpDBGrid: TDBGrid;

begin
  FormSelectEmp := TForm.Create(Self);
  SelectEmpDBGrid :=  TDBGrid.Create(Self);
  SelectEmpDBGrid.Parent := FormSelectEmp;
  SelectEmpDBGrid.Align := alClient;
  SelectEmpDBGrid.DataSource := DMl.DataSourceGetEmpList;
  SelectEmpDBGrid.OnDblClick := AddSelectedEmp;
  FormSelectEmp.ShowModal;