# How to use the OnInfoMessage event on a Connection that isn't created with a component but with code?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, event-handling

I am trying to make a progress bar on database backup and restore. The backup and restore blocks of code work fine and they are separated in other threads looking like this:

```
type
  TThreadBackUp = class( TThread )
  protected
    procedure Execute(); override;
  public
    DataSource : TMSDataSource;
    Connection : TMSConnection;
    Query : TMSQuery;
    var DBName : string;
    var BackUpFile : string;
end;
```

I've shown only the backup thread because the restore is similar.
I've managed to find a way to track the progress of the query with "Stats = 1". Here is the code of the backup thread

```
procedure TThreadBackUp.Execute();
begin
  Query.SQL.Text := 'BACKUP DATABASE ' + DBName +
    ' TO DISK = ' + QuotedStr(BackUpFile) +
    ' WITH CHECKSUM, INIT, STATS = 1';

  Query.Execute;
end;
```

And here is how I call the thread

```
CreateBackUp := BackUpThread.TThreadBackUp.Create(True);
  CreateBackUp.FreeOnTerminate := True;
  try
    CreateBackUp.DataSource := MSDSChanges;
    CreateBackUp.Connection := MSConnLyubenAirport;
    CreateBackUp.Query := MSQChanges;
    CreateBackUp.DBName := CreateBackUp.Connection.Database;
    CreateBackUp.BackUpFile := odlgOpenBackUp.FileName;
    CreateBackUp.Start;
  except on EConvertError do
    CreateBackUp.Free;
  end;
```

Since I'm not using the main thread, I've created connection, query and datasource, that only exist in the thread. My idea is to update the progress bar every time the connection receives a message from "Stats = 1". But since the connection is made with code in the thread and not with a component, I don't know how to use the OnInfoMessage event. My question is whether my idea is good and if yes, how to use the event?

Comment: How about [asking where you bought it](https://support.devart.com/portal/en/community)? From their [documentation](https://docs.devart.com/sdac/devart.sdac.tmsconnection.oninfomessage.htm) I cannot see how `TMSConnectionInfoMessageEvent` is defined, but that's the method you have to define and then assign your method's name to the `.OnInfoMessage` property of your object. For this basic knowledge read [How can i handle events in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42956399/4299358)

Comment: This code shows you assigning a `Connection` object that exists outside of the thread. Where is the actual object created? If you were truly creating objects "in the thread", you would be doing that inside the thread's `Execute()` , but you are not. Which makes me wonder if you are actually creating these objects at all, or just using design-time objects instead.  We can't see either way, because you left that detail out.